# Typecasting a pointer variable twice, why?

Tags: c, pointers

I have found the following code in my lecture book, it works as intended, there is no error, i am just trying to understand it. In the code, we create a char array and an int_pointer. We are able to traverse the char array with the int pointer by typecasting it to a char pointer, such that everytime it gets incremented we move exactly 1 byte forward, instead of 4.

Now my question is why we typecast 2 times. In line 13 (where the comment is) there is the "inner" typecast of (char *) and additionally the "outer" typecast (int *). I understand why the inner typecast is necessary, but why do we need the outer one? I have removed it and yet everything stays the same.

What amazes me even more is that by typecasting it back into an int *pointer, the expected length of the referenced data becomes 4 again and yet, when it gets dereferenced it prints out char after char, which indicates that only 1 byte is actually read out, even though we use a pointer that is of type int*, which usually reads 4 bytes from where the pointer points to. How can that be?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i;

    char char_array[5] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
    int int_array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    char *char_pointer;
    int *int_pointer;

    char_pointer = (char *) int_array; // Typecast into the
    int_pointer = (int *) char_array; // pointer's data type

    for (int i=0; i < 5;i++){ // Iterate through the char array with the int_pointer
        printf("[integer pointer] points to %p, which contains the char '%c'\n",
               int_pointer, *int_pointer);
  /* Line 13 */      int_pointer = (int *) ((char *) int_pointer + 1); 

    }

    for (int i=0; i < 5;i++){ // Iterate through the int array with the char_pointer
        printf("[char pointer] points to %p, which contains the integer '%d'\n",
               char_pointer, *char_pointer);
        char_pointer = (char *) ((int *) char_pointer + 1);

    } }
```

OUTPUT

```
[integer pointer] points to 000000000061FE03, which contains the char 'a'
[integer pointer] points to 000000000061FE04, which contains the char 'b'
[integer pointer] points to 000000000061FE05, which contains the char 'c'
[integer pointer] points to 000000000061FE06, which contains the char 'd'
[integer pointer] points to 000000000061FE07, which contains the char 'e'
[char pointer] points to 000000000061FDE0, which contains the integer '1'
[char pointer] points to 000000000061FDE4, which contains the integer '2'
[char pointer] points to 000000000061FDE8, which contains the integer '3'
[char pointer] points to 000000000061FDEC, which contains the integer '4'
[char pointer] points to 000000000061FDF0, which contains the integer '5'
```

Comment: @spectras: since there's no C++ specific stuff in that question, I've adjusted the tags. Just as an aside, your cert for solidabstractions appears to have expired, you may want to look into that :-) It looks like it has some good articles I'll be checking out. Cheers.

Comment: @paxdiablo> It does need some love, but you know how it is with maintaining websites, my list of "to-write" has been growing without me actually publishing stuff for almost 2 years now. But thanks for the message, it's the kind of things that give motivation to work on it :)

Answer (score 4):

You would be very unlikely to see code like that outside an environment where they're just trying to teach you how things *may* work under the covers :-)

But I'll answer *one* question at least:

> the expected length of the referenced data becomes 4 again and yet, when it gets dereferenced it prints out char after char, which indicates that only 1 byte is actually read out ...

No, the expression `*int_pointer` *will* read out four bytes (or as many bytes as is needed to make an `int`). What you're seeing there is the undefined behaviour of mismatching a format specifier with a different data type to what's expected. The standard is quite explicit (ISO C11 in this case):

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

What's *probably* happening with your code in this case is that it's just using the least significant eight bits of the `int`.

---

And, just as an aside, it doesn't actually make *any* difference what the original type of a pointer is when you cast it to another type and perform arithmetic on it (expect for the possibility of having non-aligned pointers which is fatal in some environments).

The arithmetic is performed on the *cast* type, not the original:

```
int_pointer =  (int  *) ((char *) int_pointer  + 1);
char_pointer = (char *) ((int *)  char_pointer + 1);
//                       \___________________/
//                                 |
//                This is what you're adding one to,
//              the pointer as if it was another type.
```

The first of those advances the pointer by *one* memory location regardless of the fact it uses an `int` pointer, because the additice expression is being given a `char` pointer due to the cast.

Similarly, the second advances by `sizeof(int)`, even though it's adjusting (eventually) a `char` pointer.

Comment: It would not be a violation of C11 to do `(int*)((void*)int_pointer + 1)`, right?

Comment: @DanielWalker: no, I believe that's UB: `void` is an incomplete object as per `C11 6.2.5/19` and pointer addition requires the pointer to point at a complete object as per `C11 6.5.6/2`.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is answered by @paxdiablo, with a very well conceptual explanation but I'll add a couple of lines to make it easier to visualize.

Breaking down the line `int_pointer = (int *)((char *) int_pointer + 1);`:

```
// set the int_pointer to point to the starting address of the char_array
int_pointer = (int *) char_array;
// treat the int_pointer as if it's a character pointer
(char *) int_pointer
// add 1 to that pointer *** adds 1 byte only ***
(char *) int_pointer + 1
// then, switch back and treat that pointer as if it's an integer pointer again
int_pointer = (int *) ((char *) int_pointer + 1);
```

And, breaking down the line `char_pointer = (char *)((int *) char_pointer + 1);`:

```
// set the char_pointer to point to the starting address of the int_array
char_pointer = (char *) int_array;
// treat the char_pointer as if it's an integer pointer
(int *) char_pointer
// add 1 to that pointer *** adds 4 bytes ***
(int *) char_pointer + 1
// then, switch back and treat that pointer as if it's a character pointer again
char_pointer = (char *)((int *) char_pointer + 1);
```

Then the magic of the `printf` function comes into play... If a `printf` function is to print the value of a dereferenced pointer, `printf` treats that same address according to the corresponding format specifier:

```
printf("dereferencing same address as int %d and as char %c\n", *char_pointer, *char_pointer);
// printf takes the same memory address, namely the value of "char_pointer"
// first, treats the 4 bytes as if it's an integer
// then, treats the single byte as if it's a character
```

and same as above;

```
printf("dereferencing same address as int %d and as char %c\n", *int_pointer, *int_pointer);
// printf takes the same memory address, namely the value of "int_pointer"
// first, treats the 4 bytes as if it's an integer
// then, treats the single byte as if it's a character
```